# How do you retry an HTTP request to an API if the response code is other than "200 OK"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, http, request, response

I'm making requests to an external API that 9 out of 10 times returns a JSON string that I use to create records in my own App.

That one time though, it will return an "Internal Server Error" (code 500), crashing the rest of my App as it tries to parse a `nil` JSON String.

How can I retry the external API call if the `response.code` is other than "200 OK" ?

External API @connector (HTTP Request)

```
  def fetch_client(client_identification)
    url = URI("#{BASE_URL}/clients/#{client_identification}")

    https = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
    https.use_ssl = true

    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url)
    request["Authorization"] = "Bearer 1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm"

    response = https.request(request)
  end
```

My Adapter that does something with the response (it fails as it tries to parse an empty string)

```
  def get_client(client_identification)
    response = @connector.fetch_client(client_identification)

    # how to retry if response.code != "200" ?

    JSON.parse(response.body) # crash
  end
```

I've tried something like this but my code fails to compile throwing an `"Invalid retry"` error

```
retry if response.code != "200"
```

Answer (score 1):

First you are missing a lot of error handling such as `Net::ReadTimeout, Errno::ECONNRESET, Errno::ECONNABORTED, Errno::EPIPE, OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError, Timeout::Error` and probably others. For those Net::HTTP has [max_retries](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#method-i-max_retries-3D) but you'll need to `rescue` if not ok after max_retries is reached.

But for the best case scenario, you could call `get_client` again (recursion) BUT you need to set a retry limit to not get a stack overflow OR if you want to retry only once and don't care about DRY:

```
def get_client(client_identification)
   response = @connector.fetch_client(client_identification)

   if response.code != "200"
     response = @connector.fetch_client(client_identification)
   end

   response.code != "200" ? {} : JSON.parse(response.body)
   
end
```